# I am not able to add multiple div controls to a parent div control

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void lbChatFriend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChatDivContent.Visible = true;
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv.ID = "div";
            createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Yellow");
            createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "relative");
            createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red");
            createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "50px");
            createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "50px");
            createDiv.InnerHtml = " I'm a div ";
            string chatFriend = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
            createDiv.Attributes["title"] = chatFriend;
            ChatDivContent.Controls.Add(createDiv);
        }
 <div id="ChatDivContent">
     <DIV id="div" style="background-color:Yellow;position:relative;color:Red;height:50px;width:50px;"
 title="dinesh"> I'm a div </DIV></div>
```

<----This is my output on every postback

Wnat am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not telling us what should happen, you are not telling us what is happening... that is what you are doing wrong ;-)

Comment: My guess is that you are adding this `div` on the click of some button or link, and you are expecting it to stillbe there on the 2nd click. Are you creating the *first* div again on the 2nd postback, because the server will not automatically add it again

Comment: Is there only one div possible per parent div(with multiple parents on the page) or multiple?

Comment: Probably the same case with that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555667/asp-net-adding-row-to-a-table-in-update-panel/11555764#11555764

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're not recreating the old controls on postback(f.e. when the user clicks on that `LinkButton`). Therefor only the recently  created div is displayed.

You have to recreate all dynamically created controls on every postback(in load event at the latest).
You also have to ensure that they get the same ID as before to trigger events and maintain ViewState.

If you know the number of controls to create(which could be stored in `ViewState`) you can derive the ID from the counter variable by appending it to the control-id. Then you can recreate them with the correct ID  in page's `init` event.

Recommandable readings:

- [TRULY Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)
- [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Or you use one of the builtin [Data-Bound Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) like [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) that do this automatically. You only have to set their `DataSource` and call `DataBind()`.

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276160/284240) is an answer of me on a similar question with implementation.